# How does Generator::send work?

Tags: php, generator

Usually I'm not confused about language constructs, but I can't make heads or tails of what's going on here.

```
<?php

function action() {
    for($i=0; $i<10; ++$i) {
        $ans = (yield expensive($i));
        echo "action $ans\n";
    }
}

function expensive($i) {
    return $i*2;
}

$gen = action();
foreach($gen as $x) {
    echo "loop $x\n";
    $gen->send($x);
}
```

Prints:

```
loop 0
action 0
action 
loop 4
action 4
action 
loop 8
action 8
action 
loop 12
action 12
action 
loop 16
action 16
action
```

So every 2nd iteration of my loop is skipped, and I'm getting `NULL` for `$ans` periodically. What??

I thought `$ans` would receive the result of [`$gen->send`](http://php.net/manual/en/generator.send.php), and if I didn't send anything before the next `yield`, *then* `$ans` would be null, but I always send something on each iteration, so what's is going on here?

Comment: Try inverting the order. I think (not sure though) you need to send it before it can be used in the echo within the generator.

Comment: @apokryfos Inverting the order of what now? I can't print `$ans` before it's defined. Maybe the `foreach` is messing it up...

Comment: I was saying `$gen->send($x); echo "loop $x\n";` and compare the difference instead of the current `echo -> send` combo

Answer (score 4):

It's a documentation problem. Here's what a PHP developer [wrote on a bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76104):

> `next()` and `send()` both advance the generator. That's how generators work. Using `next()`, explicitly or implicitly, means there's no way to pass a value back through the yield and thus the code will get null - just like when trying to get the return value from a function that doesn't return anything.

In other words, you can't use `send()` inside a `foreach` and expect meaningful results.

---

Actual `foreach` call `next()` [after each iteration](http://php.net/manual/en/iterator.next.php).

```
/** @return Generator */
function action() {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i += 1) {
        $answer = (yield $i * 2);
        echo "received: $answer\n";
    }
}


$gen = action();
while ($gen->valid()) {
    $x = $gen->current();
    echo "sending $x\n";
    $gen->send($x);
    $gen->next();
}
```

Now that we added it, the code starts to misbehave again:

```
sending 0
received: 0
received: 
sending 4
received: 4
received: 
sending 8
received: 8
```

If we remove the offending `next()` the code works as one can expect.

```
$gen = action();
while ($gen->valid()) {
    $x = $gen->current();
    echo "sending $x\n";
    $gen->send($x);
    //$gen->next();
}
```

Outputs:

```
sending 0
received: 0
sending 2
received: 2
sending 4
received: 4
sending 6
received: 6
sending 8
received: 8
```

Sounds like a bug for me. [Even HHVM fails with a fatal error.](https://3v4l.org/OR3qW)

Answer (score 1):

I think the 'foreach' is messing things up. When the foreach loop starts, an iterator is created, and I guess it can't handle the fact that I'm injecting new things into the generator.

This:

```
<?php

/**
 * @return Generator
 */
function action() {
    for($i=0; $i<10; ++$i) {
        $ans = (yield expensive($i));
        echo "action $ans\n";
    }
}

function expensive($i) {
    return $i*2;
}

$gen = action();
while($gen->valid()) {
    $x = $gen->current();
    echo "loop $x\n";
    $gen->send($x);
}
```

Prints what I'd expect:

```
loop 0
action 0
loop 2
action 2
loop 4
action 4
loop 6
action 6
loop 8
action 8
loop 10
action 10
loop 12
action 12
loop 14
action 14
loop 16
action 16
loop 18
action 18
```

Things get weird again though if you `send` more than once per loop:

```
<?php

/**
 * @return Generator
 */
function action() {
    for($i=0; $i<10; ++$i) {
        $ans = (yield expensive($i));
        echo "action $ans\n";
    }
}

function expensive($i) {
    echo "expensive $i\n";
    return $i;
}

$gen = action();
while($gen->valid()) {
    $x = $gen->current();
    echo "loop $x\n";
    $gen->send($x);
    $gen->send($x);
}
```

Prints:

```
expensive 0
loop 0
action 0
expensive 1
action 0
expensive 2
loop 2
action 2
expensive 3
action 2
expensive 4
loop 4
action 4
expensive 5
action 4
expensive 6
loop 6
action 6
expensive 7
action 6
expensive 8
loop 8
action 8
expensive 9
action 8
```

I think what's happening here is that `send` is causing `action` to iterate twice for every one `while` iteration. If we remove the two `sends()` then we get stuck in an infinite loop. So... `send()` is advancing the iterator, whereas `current()` does not. And I think this explains what was going on with the `foreach` loop too -- both the `foreach` and `send()` were advancing the iterator, which is why every other result was being skipped!